# CentOS "Kernel configuration is invalid" error when building Guest Additions

Tags: linux, centos

I've installed CentOS through VirtualBox on my Windows 10 machine.  I know that installing guest additions (devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image) will install guest additions, but when building the guest additions I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid. include/generated/autoconfig.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.

Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it
```

I've navigated to the /usr/src/ directory and executed the recommended commands, but I get:

```
make *** No rule to make target 'oldconfig'. Stop.
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I usually find (1) kernel headers are missing, or (2) yum upgrade needs to be run. Are both the kernel and headers up to date?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: on the same boat as of now, unable to figure out a way ahead.

Answer (score 0):

**I couldn't make this work, but do hear me out for a work around.**

RHEL made a release of 7.6 on 30th October, 2018 which messed the Guest Additions on Virtual Box. Check [this link for release schedules](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078)

With this screwed up Guest Additions I faced multiple troubles of:

- Mouse right click not working on apps opened inside virtual box.
- Mouse completely stopping to work after sometime.

The only vital solution was to upgrade to release 7.5 (I had also tried upgrading to VirtualBox 6.0 hoping the Guest Addition might compile on the latest kernel)

The steps I followed to upgrade from this blog link - [Digitolle](https://digitolle.wordpress.com/2017/10/26/how-to-upgrade-centos-to-a-specific-version/)

Hope this helps.